# Drop-down menu not working bootstrap

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a web site with bootstrap and the navbar dropdown its not working, I tried to change de color and that's where it screwed up but i can´t find why

http://bootply.com/94426

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a problem with your class "navbar-custom1"

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">


       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">drop-down item <b class="caret"></b> </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">item</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                 <li>
                    <a href="#">item</a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Facebook</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>


    </div>
</div>
```

above snapper is working fine.... try to adjust your formatting with it.....